# How can a audio file be encoded as base64 string to be used in Speech-To-Text API (https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize)

Tags: artificial-intelligence, audio-recording, speech-to-text, video-encoding, google-speech-api

Facing an issue while consuming the Google Speech-To-Text API from the client-side.
I have been recording the voice through a library "https://www.npmjs.com/package/recordrtc" and sending the encoded data as base64 to the Speech-To-Text API but the API is responding the blank object.
Most probably, there might be an encoding issue. Could anyone help me with this?

Comment: The following page discusses different ways to base64 encode audio data: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/base64-encoding.  You can try a couple different ways to encode and see if you are matching.  You may also want to take the library you mention out of the equation and start with a simple audio file for testing.

Comment: I have tried with an audio file in which bitrate is 16 and sampleRate is 16000 and it works. But now, I want to encode the recorded audio. The issue I'm facing is that the MediaRecorder API doesn't allow to change the bitrate of the recorder(MediaRecorder) as mentioned on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API